# How to checkbox checked default single and multiple checkbox? ng-init="checkboxModel.value=true" its not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs, angular

```html
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value" ng-true-value="'true'" ng-false-value="'false'" ng-click='checkboxClick(checkboxModel.value, index);' ng-init="checkboxModel.value=true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var demoApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
demoApp.controller('languageController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.languages = [
      {id:1, name:'C#'},
      {id:2, name:'MVC'},
      {id:3, name:'SQL'},
      {id:4, name:'AngularJs'},
      {id:5, name:'jQuery'},
      {id:6, name:'Javascript'},
      {id:7, name:'HTML'},
      {id:8, name:'CSS'},
      {id:9, name:'Linq'},
      {id:10, name:'EntityFramework'}
    ];
    
    $scope.defaultSelected = [
      {id:2, name:'MVC'},
      {id:4, name:'AngularJs'}
    ];
    
    $scope.checkID = function(name){
      var dat = $scope.defaultSelected.find(v=> v.name === name);
      if(dat) {return true }else{ return false}
    }

    $scope.submit = function() {
        $scope.result = $scope.loopData;
    };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="myApp">
        <div class="wrapper wrapper-content middlealigen col-sm-12" ng-controller="languageController">
            
            <div ng-repeat="language in languages">
                
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="language.checked" id="language{{$index}}" ng-checked="checkID(language.name)" />
                
                <label for="language{{$index}}" ng-bind="language.name"></label>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
```